# Move to tip of github pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I checked out a friend's pull request using `git checkout pr/10` after adding this to my .git/config:

```
[branch "pr/10"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/pr/10
```

Then I did a bunch of stuff that I can't remember, and now when I type `git log` the first commit is one from the main repo, not my friend's pull request. I tried `git checkout pr/10` again but it doesn't help.

**How can I move my HEAD to the tip of the pull request again?**

One thing I tried was `git checkout 1a234b5`, where I copied `1a234b5` from the last commit on the pull request page on GitHub. That seems to move HEAD to the right place, but then when I type `git branch` it says `(detached from 1a234b5)`.

Comment: ah, one thing I just tried that worked was `git branch -D pr/10` `git checkout pr/10`. I wonder if there's a less destructive way to do it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply execute a "I want this branch to point to this commit":

```
git checkout pr/10  # Checkout the branch
git reset --hard 1a234b5  # Move it 1a234b5.
```

You might also be able to say:

```
git checkout pr/10
git reset --hard origin/pr/10
```

Note that command will reset your working directory and index (due to `--hard`, feel free to leave that off), so if you have changes, `git stash` them first.

The `git branch -D`, `git checkout` thing works because `git`, not able to find a branch named `pr/10`, but seeing that one is in your remote with that name, will create a new branch at the point where your remote branch is, thus recreating it in the right spot.